# Migrate data from NoSQL to an RDBMS

Tags: nosql, hbase, relational-database, amazon-aurora

We have data existing in HBase and we want to move to AWS Aurora (MySQL) and we need to use the existing data so have to somehow load the NoSQL data into Aurora.

It's not a very big data base. Just a few tables.

Are there any best practices/tools to migrate data from NoSQL to a relational DB? I saw a lot of questions on the internet that ask to the reverse (DB -> NoSQL) but my requirement is a bit different and I don't find any helpful information.

Can someone please help? Where do I even start?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this without writing too much custom code would be to use Spark-HBase Connector from Hortonworks (SHC) to read data from an HBase table into a Spark dataframe and to write that dataframe into a MySQL table. The key challenge would be to get SHC to work, because in my experience it's extremely version sensitive. So the trick is to correctly coordinate your version of Spark, HBase, and SHC (and finding that right combination is trickier than you may think).

However, if you manage to get all the dependencies right, then doing the above is a matter of a few lines of code in Jupyter Notebook or Pyspark. You could run this on Yarn to parallelize the workload, in case it's large. Should work. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the idea to try out. I come from an SQL background and so what I'm also having trouble with is creating a mental picture of how to create RDBMS tables for accommodating data coming from NoSQL tables with `column-families` instead of `columns`.  Does a dataframe help there? Should the RDB table just reflect the structure of a dataframe?

Comment: If you google a few python examples of how SHC works, it will be quite intuitive -- you define a Table Catalog in your Python code, which maps the HBase row and column(s) into the Dataframe columns (the HBase row is treated as the first column). From there, you can map your dataframe onto the MySQL table almost 1-to-1 as you would normally do. Almost any example you google on this should work, but the real trick is just integrating the versions to make sure they are all interoperable (otherwise you'll be getting lots of ClassNotFound exceptions or NoSuchMethod exceptions).